# Sump Pump Set Up

Tags: sump-pump, sump

I have two pipes coming from my sump. One sends water outside to an underground pipe. The water is then expelled through a French drain in the yard away from the house. The second pipe comes through the foundation a few inches.It is near the first pipe but points straight down. It looks like erosion is taking place under the second pipe. The batteries, charger, and pump were just replaced. Has there been an error made?

Comment: Second pipe sounds like a inlet, to drain water to sump from foundation.  Good pictures would help.  Most sump pumps only have one output pipe, but sump pit can have inlets.

Comment: crip659 is correct.  It is the outlet of the floor drain pipe, that shall sit above the pump float.

Comment: Inlet to sump pit should be under the cement, in the stone base.  The stones/gravel is what you are probably seeing.

Comment: Is your pit normally sealed? It could be a vent but most likely an entrance since there is some erosion.